# Import undelimited flat file with panda python

Tags: python

I'm a data analyst and I work a lot with SPSS. However, I want to learn datascience with Python. I looked for how to import a flat file by slicing it into a column with python and I didn't see.

Here is part of the content of the file to import:
[image]

Explanation:

for each line: the columns from 0 to 6 represent the personnel number of an agent, from 7 to 9, an element code of his remuneration, from 25 to 32, the salary of the agent, and so on until the end .

How to import this file with python and transform it into dataframe??
This is how I import it with spss but I don't know how to import it as a dataframe with python:
[image]

Big thanks.

I don't know how to do this with ptyhon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "for each line: the columns from 0 to 6 represent the personnel number of an agent, from 7 to 9, an element code of his remuneration, from 25 to 32, the salary of the agent, and so on until the end ." **How do you know** this? What is the rule that tells you these numbers? How can we understand the "and so on" part? I don't see any pattern in the numbers.

Comment: Also: [please do not upload images of code, data or errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) We [will not transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) them for you. It is important for us to have the text, so that we can copy and paste - first in order to test the code, and second to help write an answer that refers to the original.

Comment: Anyway, please try looking at [some of these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+fixed+width+column) first.